# What shall I do, if C compares two doubles wrong?

Tags: c, double, comparison, precision

I want to write a fmod() function

```
double fmod(double x, double y) {
    double mod = x;

    while(mod >= y)
    {
        mod -= y;
    }
    
    return mod;
}
```

But fmod(1.2, 0.05) returns 0.05

Comment: Don't name your functions the same as library functions.  Also, try printing with `%.17f`.

Comment: Now It returns 0.04999999999999946

Comment: Please take a bit time to check description of the tags you add to your question. `FMOD` is not related to your function.

Comment: Better not call `fmod(1, -1)` :)

Answer (score 4):

Although the title asks about incorrect comparison, the comparison in the program shown is correct. It is the only correct floating-point operation in the program; all the others have errors (compared to real-number arithmetic).

In `fmod(1.2, 0.05)`, neither 1.2 nor 0.5 are representable in the `double` format used in your C implementation. These numerals in source code are rounded to the nearest representable values, 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 and 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125.

Then, in the subtraction in `mod -= y;`, the exact real arithmetic result, 1.14999999999999995281552145343084703199565410614013671875 is not representable, so it is rounded to 1.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375.

Similar errors continue during the calculations, until eventually 0.0499999999999994615418330567990778945386409759521484375 is produced. At each point, the comparison `mod >= y` correctly evaluates whether `mod` is greater than or equal to `y`. When `mod` is less than `y`, the loop stops.

However, due to intervening errors, the result produced, 0.0499999999999994615418330567990778945386409759521484375, is not equal to the residue of 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 divided by 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125. The correct result can be calculated with the standard `fmod` function, which returns 0.04999999999999989175325509904723730869591236114501953125.

Note that, when you define a function named `fmod`, the C standard does not define the behavior because this conflicts with the standard library function of that name. You ought to give it a different name, such as `fmodAlternate`.

Inside the `fmod` routine, errors can be avoided. It is possible to implement `fmod` so that it returns an exact result for the arguments it is given. (This is possible because the result is always in a region of the floating-point range that is fine enough [has a low enough exponent] to represent the real arithmetic result exactly.) However, the errors in providing the arguments cannot be corrected: It is not possible to represent 1.2 or 0.05 in the `double` format your C implementation uses. The source code `fmod(1.2, .05)` will always calculate `fmod(1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125)`, which is 0.04999999999999989175325509904723730869591236114501953125.

An alternative is to represent the numbers differently. For example, you could scale these numbers by a factor of 100, and `fmod(120, 5)` will return 0. What solution is appropriate depends on the circumstances of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: And notice: the loop multiplies the small approximation error by the number of loops, (10000.2, 0.5) would be produce an inacceptable result.

Comment: Thank You! I understand